# How to checking if the column-entity already exists in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am updating a branch in my function. The function takes the input parameters and updates the branch. However, I am trying to check if the input branch-code already exists; if it already exists for any other branch of that company. I have a constraint where different companies can have same branch codes. Hence, I didnt use unique attribute on branch_code. I have tried the following. However, it doesnt seem to work.

```
        $branch_info = CompanyBranch::where(['branch_code' => $request['branch_code'], 'company_id' => 1])->get(['branch_code']);

        if (sizeof($branch_info) > 1) {
            return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'A Branch already exists with Branch-code ' . $request['branch_code']];
        }
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Try `$branch_info->count()` instead of `sizeof($branch_info)`.

Comment: And `> 1` means at least 2 already exist, you need `> 0`.

Comment: @TheFallen I dont want the check to be like .. if it already exists( which is what we are already updating); and it still will flash me the error

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
if(count($branch_info) > 0){
   //record exists   
}else{
  // record not exists    
}
```

Comment: In my case, it will always go in record exists for your answer